# Chinese remainder theorem in abelian categories

Tags: abelian-categories, chinese-remainder-theorem

The chinese remainder theorem holds in arbitrary abelian categories?
I found a generalization in homological categories, but i'm looking for a proof in valid in an abelian category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find for myself the following proof: we can obtain obtain the chinese theorem by applying nine lemma to the following diagram:

$\begin {matrix}
&0&0&0&\\
&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\\
0\to&H\cap K\to&H\oplus K\to&H+K\to&0\\
&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\\
0\to&G\to&G\oplus G\to&G\to&0\\
&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\\
0\to&G/ H\cap K\to&G/H\oplus G/K\to&G/H+K\to&0\\
&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\\
&0&0&0&\\
\end {matrix} $